How to Set Default Logging Verbosity in ROS 2?
Is there a way to set the default logging verbosity for all nodes launched in ROS 2? I have a launch file that I run and at the beginning it outputs to the console [INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO which indicates to me there is a way to set the default logging verbosity.
I'm asking this in part because I have a launch file as a part of an installed ROS 2 package that launches many nodes that all log to the console, preventing me from being able to easily read the log information from my own nodes I am trying to debug. I understand I can set the log level of nodes individually within a launch file, but in this case the nodes are launched via an uneditable launch file and I feel that there must be a better way than me copying the launch file and editing it, especially since there are many other nested launch files with other nodes that are called.
I have seen the ROS 2 documentation on Logging here, but it doesn't include anything about a default logging level.

The following is possible:
ros2 run package node --ros-args --log-level DEBUG --log-level rcl:=INFO
This sets loglevel to DEBUG for all except for rcl.
You can add also others, e.g.:
ros2 run package node --ros-args --log-level DEBUG --log-level rcl:=INFO --log-level rclcpp:=INFO
Or, you can set the loglevel for one (or more) loggers specifically, e.g.:
ros2 run package node --ros-args --log-level FATAL --log-level my_logger_name:=DEBUG
However, there is currently no similar functionality for launch files, i.e. the following is not possible:
ros2 launch demo_nodes_cpp talker_listener.launch.py --ros-args --log-level debug
There is a feature request for this here, which mentions your use case:

An issue with this for me is when I am including other launch files from external packages, in which case I cannot add the extra arguments.


Thanks for the answer. Bummer the feature is not available, hopefully they add it one day

There is one other possibility that I just thought of: you can set the loglevel through a service call since Iron, see this example. So it is technically possible to change node loglevels at runtime...

Worth mentioning about the loglevel service, is that this issue is still open, so it there is a non-zero possibility that using the loglevel service leads to a crash.

That might be an option to explore, thanks for sharing
